# How can I Limit nodes on each level of children in tree with cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-theory

I'm using cypher and neo4j
I have a big dataset of parent and child relations as

```
(:Person)-[:PARENT_OF*]-(:Person)
```

**I need to get the family tree with only 5 children(nodes) on each level of the tree**

I've tried:

```
MATCH path = (jon:Person )-[:PARENT_OF*]-(:Person)
WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value
RETURN value;
```

its returning me the whole tree structure, I've tried limiting the nodes with limit but it isn't working properly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to filter out the paths first. My approach would be to make sure that all children in the path are among the first 5 child nodes of the previous parent . I don't have a dataset ready to test it, but it could be along the lines of this

```
MATCH path = (jon:Person )-[:PARENT_OF*]->(leaf:Person)
// limit the number of paths, by only considering the ones that are not parent of someone else.
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person)

// and all nodes in the path (except the first one, the root) be in the first five children of the parent
AND 

ALL(child in nodes(path)[1..] WHERE child IN [(sibling)<-[:PARENT_OF]-(parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child) | sibling][..5])

WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value
RETURN value
```

another approach, perhaps faster, would be to first collect all the first five children of descendants of jon

```
// find all sets of "firstFiveChildren"
MATCH (jon:Person { name:'jon'}),
     (p:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
WHERE EXISTS((jon)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(p))
WITH jon,p,COLLECT(child)[..5] AS firstFiveChildren
// create a unique list of the persons that could be part of the tree
WITH jon,apoc.coll.toSet(
 apoc.coll.flatten(
   [jon]+COLLECT(firstFiveChildren)
 )
) AS personsInTree


MATCH path = (jon)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(leaf:Person)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person)
AND ALL(node in nodes(path) WHERE node IN personsInTree)
WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value
RETURN value;
```

UPDATE

The issue with the data is that the tree is not symmetric, e.g. not all the paths have the same depth. node d0 for instance has no children. So if you pick five children at the first level, you may not be getting any deeper.

I added a slightly different approach, that should work with symmetric trees, and which allows you to set the number max number of children per node.  Try it with 3, and you will see that you only get nodes from the first level., with 8 you get more.

```
// find all sets of "firstChildren"
WITH 8 AS numberChildren

MATCH (jon:Person { name:'00'}),
       (p:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
WHERE EXISTS((jon)-[:PARENT_OF*0..]->(p))
WITH jon,p,COLLECT(child)[..numberChildren] AS firstChildren

// create a unique list of the persons that could be part of the tree
WITH jon,apoc.coll.toSet(
 apoc.coll.flatten(
   [jon]+COLLECT(firstChildren)
 )
) AS personsInTree



MATCH path = (jon)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(leaf:Person)
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person)
AND ALL(node in nodes(path) WHERE node IN personsInTree)

WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value
RETURN value
```

Comment: for creating dataset you can use this cypher
CREATE (r:Person {id: 0, name: '00'})
FOREACH (i IN range(1,5)|
         CREATE (r)-[:PARENT_OF]->(c:Person { id:i, name: 'd'+i}));
MATCH (c:Person)
         FOREACH (j IN range(1,5)|
            CREATE (c)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person { id:c.id*10+j, name: 'a'+c.id*10+j }));
MATCH (c:Person)
         FOREACH (j IN range(1,5)|
            CREATE (c)-[:PARENT_OF]->(:Person { id:c.id*10+j, name: 'd'+c.id*10+j }));

Comment: I've tried your solution but it is not working for my use case...
what i actually want to achieve is get the first level 5 child and five five children for each of the first level children and so on

Comment: Thanks in advanced for helping me out